# Hardware implementations of floating-point numbers have uses for "negative zero"; is there any use for "imaginary negative zero"?

Tags: complex-numbers, floating-point

I've been studying low-level hardware implementations of floating point numbers and doing an exercise to design a custom floating point implementation.

I know that being able to represent negative zero is important for some purposes, but ran across a curious question.

Complex numbers are generally represented by two floating point numbers. Is there any use in being able to represent negative zero on the imaginary line? Does anybody use this for anything?

Comment: Having a difference between "positive zero" and "negative zero" is almost exclusively useful as a convenience for programming applications.  There is otherwise no mathematical difference between them; they are both representations of the same number, what we call "zero," with no additional qualification needed.  Could letting there be an "imaginary zero" and "negative imaginary zero" be useful for a programmer?  Perhaps in some contexts, sure.  Is it common or relevant to maths in general?  No, not at all.

Comment: I am not sufficiently familiar with real-life use case for complex-number computation to answer, but would like to point out that the concept of negative zero is useful in floating-point computations because floating-point numbers exhibit point-interval dualism. Therefore a floating-point zero could either represent a point (i.e., mathematical zero) or an interval comprising all numbers too small in magnitude to be represented in a given floating-point format (and in particular, the results of severe underflow in previous computation).